# Creating a byte type from a String in Java

Tags: java, byte

I have this string `11110000`, which represents a `byte`.

I want to create a `byte` from that string, but I can't find any example on-line.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I found loads of stuff online in seconds.  Let me guess - your actual homework question stipulates 'You must not use ParseInt or any other library calls'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int value = Integer.parseInt(s, 2); // 2 for binary`

If you want byte type:

`byte value = Byte.parseByte(s, 2); // 2 for binary`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Byte#parseByte()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: BTW, Java bytes are signed, so [`11110000` is out of range](http://ideone.com/clone/m5fI9).

Comment: That's the reason I suggest to use Integer.parseInt.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("11111",2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte myByte = (byte)Integer.parseInt("11110000", 2);
```